# TableView is not working in iOS device

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I am working on Xamarin  iOS app development  project through visual studio..But I am facing the problem defined below:

When I select a **tableView** from toolbox in visual studio.and populating data with **UITableViewCell**.It is not deploying on device,Only the plain table view is showing without any data parsed from xml.I have written the following code under **RootViewController.cs** class file.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() 
{

base.ViewDidLoad();
var table = new UITableView(View.Bounds); // defaults to Plain style
string[] tableItems = new string[]
{ 
  "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs",  "Tubers" 
};
table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems,this);
Add(table);}
```

I cannot understanding what i am missing.

**UPDATE**

My TableSource.cs class looks like...

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;

namespace App6
{
    // ReSharper disable once ClassNeverInstantiated.Global
    public partial class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        readonly string[] _tableItems;
        string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";
        readonly RootViewController _owner;

        public TableSource(string[] items)
        {
            _tableItems = items;
        }
            public TableSource (string[] items, RootViewController owner)
            {
                  this._owner = owner;
            }
        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return _tableItems.Length;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
            string item = _tableItems[indexPath.Row];

            //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null)
            { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UIAlertController okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create ("Row Selected", _tableItems[indexPath.Row], UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            _owner.PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: what does your TableSource class look like?

Comment: @Jason I have attached my TableSource Class

Answer (score 1):

in your Source class's constructor

```
public TableSource (string[] items, RootViewController owner)
{
  this._owner = owner;
}
```

you are not assigning _tableItems so it will always be empty.  Add this

```
_tableItems = items;
```

like you have in your other constructor overload

Comment: have you used the debugger to verify that the methods in your source call are being called?